# Can you make a C# program which can not access to any local file system other than the folder it is installed?

Tags: c#

Let me ask whether you can make a C# program which can not access to any local file system other than the folder/sub folders it is installed? And how if the answer is yes.
For details if it is necessary and possible, users are supposed to accept the program runs under a special user account which is restricted the file access only to the folder  it is installed and to sub folders.

Thank you very much in advance.

Edit : Let me add context. I want users do not change their accounts. And as a programmer I do not have complete control over the program for some reasons.

Comment: Yes, but that is a function of the operating system and network permissions.  It has nothing to do with your program.

Comment: Shouldnt you as a programmer be able to control what files your program is making calls to or accessing? If it is a text editor for example, you can check that it can only open or save files in that file path directory.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you display a file/open dialog, the user can navigate to wherever they have permissions. Sure, you can refuse any path that doesn't meet your expectations, or even build a custom file/open dialog, but to what end?

Comment: You can sandbox .NET appdomains: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130766.aspx; I don't know how granular the permissions can be.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can you? I confirm because I want users do not change accounts ,but only the program uses a special account allowed in the installation by users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can you make a C# program which cannot access any part of the local file system other than the directory in which it is installed?

No, because every C# program will need to at the very least have access to the .NET runtime libraries, which are in the Windows install directory.

My suggestion to you is that you look into *isolated storage*. The .NET code access security system enables you to set a *policy* which states that certain programs only get to access the .NET runtime, the installed location of the code, and a special "isolated storage" directory that can be used for the application to store per-user data.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, but how you do this is complicated.

First, you need a user account with extremely limited permissions. It must be able to access files and run programs within the installation directory of the program, and that's pretty much it. You can create such a user with the installer program, using tools in the System.DirectoryServices namespace. Here's an example of creating a user:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
private void CreateUser(string userName, string password)
{
DirectorySearcher dseSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();
string rootDSE = dseSearcher.SearchRoot.Path;
string userDSE = rootDSE.Insert(7, "OU=Users,");
DirectoryEntry userDE = new DirectoryEntry(userDSE);
DirectoryEntry user = userDE.Children.Add("CN=" + userID, "user");
staff.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = userID;
staff.Properties["UserPrincipalName"].Value = userName +
@"@domain";
staff.CommitChanges();
staff.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value =
ActiveDs.ADS_USER_FLAG.ADS_UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT |
ActiveDs.ADS_USER_FLAG.ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD;
staff.CommitChanges();
staff.Invoke("SetPassword", new Object[] { password });
}
```

Now, once that's happened, you need to make sure your program normally runs in the context of that user account. You can do that by specifying the user account to run the program with in a ProcessStartInfo object, used by a "bootstrapper" program that is what you create shortcuts for. You can then also ensure the program is running in the context of that user account using Environment.CurrentUser, and abort execution of the program if it is being run by any more permissive account.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to restrict the program to a particular account, you can look up the user's credentials, and exit the program if it's not the right one.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csyx45b8.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfs49sw0.aspx